# Parallax Custom Function scroll effect issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, parallax

**Example**  http://jsfiddle.net/5MsUd/

I am having issues with this code for the scroll up and down effect. The key issue is this:

```
    //create the event listener of the users choice.
    window.addEventListener(this.trigger,function(){
        //get the current position of scroll and add it to the object
        self.scrollPos= this.scrollY || this.pageYoffset;

        //get the current position of the element
        newPos = getPosition(self.target,self.dir);

//HERE IS THE BIG ISSUE!!!!!!!
        //adjust the current position depending on the scroll direction
        if(scrollex.direction == "down"){
        self.target.style[self.dir]= newPos + (self.scrollPos * self.offset)+"px";
        }else{
        self.target.style[self.dir]= newPos - (this.scrollY * self.offset)+"px";
        }

        //run callback if there is one
        if(callback !== null && typeof callback=='function'){
            callback.call(self);
        }
    }, false);
```

I'm not getting the correct PXs to go back to the correct position. I added the fiddle as that has all the major code with notes. As well as extra functions that I've added to help assist this `scrollex` function

Can anyone suggestion a better mathematical equation to get the correct pxs back and forth. Try it out and play with it, let me know of any good suggestions. I've gone pretty deep with this and have more to add but as of now the scroll down and up part system is majorly buggy. You can see once you start scrolling back and forth it does move back and forth but moving up gives less pixels than what down did.